# merge two plots next to each other in one figure in R (no ggplot)

Tags: r

I want to generate a figure that merges two plots next to each other in the same figure, I was able to do it in excel, but it was time consuming, is it possible to do it in R, this screenshot from excel:
[image]

My data are:

```
           C
    WT  PO  RO  MO  
0   0   0   0   0   
24  3.0 2.0 1.0 3.0 
48  4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 
72  3.0 4.0 6.5 3.0 
96  7.0 2.0 4.0 3.0 
                    
        D       
    WT  PO  RO  MO  
0   0   0   0   0   
24  0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 
48  0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 
72  0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 
96  0.0 1.0 0.0 0.5
```

The problem with this figure, that was made in excel, is that the starting point of second plot extends beyond 0.

Comment: I specifically mentioned no ggplot!

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your dataframes?

Comment: @Werner no, it does not! but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-ggplot solution. Note I put the x data in a column names `x`.

```
# Make two subplots
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # 1 row with 2 columns

# Make the first plot
plot(df1$x,df1$wt,data=df1,type='b',main='First Plot',
     ylab='Titer')
lines(df1$x,df1$po,col='blue',type='b')
lines(df1$x,df1$ro,col='red',type='b')
lines(df1$x,df1$mo,col='darkgreen',type='b')


# Make the second plot
plot(df2$x,df2$wt,type='b',main='Second Plot',
     ylim=c(0,8),ylab=NA)
lines(df2$x,df2$po,col='blue',type='b')
lines(df2$x,df2$ro,col='red',type='b')
lines(df2$x,df2$mo,col='darkgreen',type='b')
```

[image: Base Plot subplots]

If you want them truly on the same x axis, you have to shift the lines for the second plot and adjust the axes ticks/labels like below.

```
# Shift the x data for the second plot

df1 = data.frame(x=c(0,24,48,72,96),
                 wt=c(0,3,4,3,7),
                 po=c(0,2,3,4,2),
                 ro=c(0,1,2,6.5,4),
                 mo=c(0,3,1,3,3))

# shift the x data for the second plot
df2 = data.frame(x=c(0,24,48,72,96) + 110,
                 wt=rep(0,5),
                 po=c(0,rep(1,4)),
                 ro=c(0,1,0,0,0),
                 mo=c(0,0,0,1,.5))

# Make the first plot
plot(df1$x,df1$wt,data=df1,type='b',main='Combined Plots',
     ylab='Titer',xlab = 'X Axis',
     xlim = c(0,210),axes=F)
lines(df1$x,df1$po,col='blue',type='b')
lines(df1$x,df1$ro,col='red',type='b')
lines(df1$x,df1$mo,col='darkgreen',type='b')


# Add lines for the second plot
lines(df2$x,df2$wt,type='b',col='black')
lines(df2$x,df2$po,col='blue',type='b')
lines(df2$x,df2$ro,col='red',type='b')
lines(df2$x,df2$mo,col='darkgreen',type='b')

# Reset the axes labels
axis(1,at=c(df1$x,df2$x),labels = rep(df1$x,2))
axis(2,at = 0:8)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, but these are separate, I want them to be in the same figure, next to each other, on the same line. Is it possible to achieve this?